# How to add item to a listbox from another class and another thread?

Tags: c#, class, listbox, delegates

I tried this:

```
partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Logging logging= new Logging();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    private void add()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            logging.add_data_to_listbox("sometext",listBox1);
        }
    }

    private void help_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(add);
    }

}

public partial class Logging
{

    public void add_data_to_listbox(string data, ListBox listbox)
    {
        MainForm mnfrm = new MainForm();

        mnfrm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff - ") + data);
        }));
    }
}
```

But i got this error message:
Additional information: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Comment: Is the form allready shown? :)

Comment: Yes but it I think this solved the problem:
Logging logging= new Logging(this);


private MainForm mMainForm;

    public Logging(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        mMainForm = mainForm;
    }

Comment: Please see my posted answer where I found more issues and described and approach with event handler

Answer (score 0):

The MainForm has got the LoggingClass as a property. Now you create the MainForm again inside the Logging?

I think you should create an EventHandler LogMessage in the Logging class and subscribe to this from the MainForm. Afterwards in the method you can handle the effent, like:

```
Logging:
// event handler
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> LogMessageReceived; 

// send log message
public void add_data_to_listbox(string data, ListBox listbox)
{
    LogMessageReceived?.Invoke(new EventArgs());
}

MainForm:
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    logging.LogMessageReceived += OnLogMessageReceived;
} 

private void OnLogMessageReceived(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // switch thread to STA thread?
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff - ") + data);
        }));
}
```

You still need to create your own custom event arguments.